# How many valid paths are there?(counting problem)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider a rectangle whose length is m and whose height is n. A path from bottom left corner to top right corner is called valid, if in each step, it either goes one unit to the right or one unit upwards. if m = 5 and n = 3, how many valid paths are there?

This rectangle is basically a table with 15 cells(3 vertical x 5 horizontal). I need to find the total number of paths that I can take from bottom left corner to top right corner. I get the answer 16 paths. Can anyone verify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you must go upwards $3$ times and rightwards $5$ times, in any order.  It sounds to me like you need to make $8$ moves, and choose $5$ of them to be rightwards, the rest will be upwards, so you should get 
$$
\binom{8}{5}=\frac{8\cdot 7\cdot 6}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}=56
$$

Comment: That make sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to think problems like this is to think the route as a binary code. In this case 1=one unit upwards and 0=one unit right. So the binary code would look like for example 10011000. So 8 digits in total. And you can choose a place for the ones in $\binom{8}{3}=56$ ways. Note that $\binom{8}{3}=\binom{8}{5}$. Do you see why?

In general the code is $m+n$ digits long where $m=$ number of ones and $n=$ number of zeroes. So the route can be chosen in $\binom{m+n}{m}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is incorrect.

Hint. For each valid path, write $a$ when you move right, and $b$ when you move up. An example of a valid path is then 
$$aababaab.$$

One way to solve the problem is first to characterize those "words" that correspond to valid paths, and then to count the number of such words by a combinatorial argument.

Comment: Ok I think I got the answer. It's integer partitioning with three variables. So it's => x1+x2+x3=8 and the restriction is x1>=1,x2>=1,x3>=1. So the answer I think is => n-1 chooses k-1 which is 42. right?

Comment: I made a mistake. It's weak restriction(x1>=0,x2>=0,x3>=0) because as long as they sum up to 8, it shouldn't matter. So, it's (n+k-1) chooses (k-1)

Comment: The person who answered 56 was correct. How long is the word supposed to be, and how many $a$'s should it have?